# Is there a way how to point vswhere.exe into a custom folder containing VS buildtools?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017-build-tools

I am trying to figure out a way how to make vswhere point into the vs buildtools on the machine that may not be properly installed. This is part of the CI pipeline where we mount the build tools through a disk. Since those are just copied and not installed, ideally I could point vswhere into the disk.

Full installation would take a long time to do everytime.